# How to youtube video using fragment

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

"I trying to play youtube video on select movie fragment below my code in Main activity but when I click on movie app close directly "

```
if (id == R.id.movie) {
    Video video=new Video();
    FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main, video, 
    video.getTag()).commit();
}
```

"Below my code In video.java In here error shown in "this"

```
public class Video extends Fragment {


    public Video() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //Recyecle view fifld
    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    //Vector for video url
    Vector<Youtubevideo> youtubevideos;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, container, false);
        recyclerView=(RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyview);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        //Load video list
        youtubevideos.add(new Youtubevideo("My video link here"));
        VideoAdapter videoAdapter=new VideoAdapter(youtubevideos);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(videoAdapter);
        return view;
    }

}
```

"Please help how to solve??"

Comment: this isnt help, but i really do love how you put your text in quotes. "so silly"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the initialization part for `youtubevideos`. Initialize it before adding any data to it.

```
youtubevideos = new Vector<>();
//Load video list
youtubevideos.add(new Youtubevideo("My video link here"));
```

Comment: Hi but error show in here Error:(41, 63) error: incompatible types: Video cannot be converted to Context                              
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

Comment: @user1464596 can you please add stack trace of error log

Comment: Error:(41, 63) error: incompatible types: Video cannot be converted to Context

Comment: instead of using this while setting the layout manager, use `getActivity()`